# How to set proxy with authentication in windows 10 using python (proxy need to be enabled for all apps, browsers included)

Tags: python, proxy

I am trying to set the a proxy for all apps running in windows 10 using python, the code is :

```
import os

#proxy_value is edited of course
proxy_value="http://username:password@ip:port" 
#proxy_value is edited of course


command='reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f'
os.system(command)


command='reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyServer /t REG_SZ /d '+proxy_value+' /f'
os.system(command)
```

but chrome keep returning this message when I try to access google.com:

> ## **This site can’t be reached**
>
> The webpage at **https://www.google.com/** might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>
> ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES

but when I use brave browser I get the "sign in" alert window for the proxy credentials even if I already used a proxy with username and password included.

when I use a proxy without authentication everything is working smoothly but once I add "username:password@" to the "ip:port"  nothing is working, so is it possible to use proxy with authentication ?

thank's a lot!